# Android EditText hint does not vertical scroll

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

This code produces a multi-line EditText.  The hint is larger than the EditText.  I would like the hint to scroll vertically when I use a finger gesture so I can see the entire hint..

[image]

When I type enough to fill the EditText, that does scroll.

```
    EditText bottomT = new EditText(context);
    bottomT.setTextSize(28);
    bottomT.setHint("A whole bunch of information....");
    bottomT.setHintTextColor(grayDarkColor);
    bottomT.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    bottomT.setBackgroundColor(grayLightColor);
    bottomT.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    bottomT.setTextColor(grayDarkColor);
    bottomT.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    bottomT.setWidth(250);
    bottomT.setHeight(200);
    bottomT.setScroller(new Scroller(model));  // DOESN'T HELP
    bottomT.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
    bottomT.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
    bottomT.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());  // DOESN'T HELP
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
  questionEntry.setScroller(new Scroller(myContext)); 
questionEntry.setMaxLines(1); 
questionEntry.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
questionEntry.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: This does not address the issue, which is to be able to scroll using a finger gesture.